# array_unique question

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I have a search engine type website. It takes the users input, stores the query as $q, explodes the query and searches the database. It then displays the results with the name and web address of each result.

For example, if i searched for "computer programming"... Stack Overflow, stackoverflow.com would be my result. However, it displays twice. (once for computer, and once for programming.)

I tried to solve this with the array_unique function, and it does not work.

any help would be appreciated.

```
    // trim whitespace

$trimmed = trim($q);
// seperate key-phrases
$trimmed_array = explode(" ", $trimmed);

// remove duplicates

$clean_array = array_unique($trimmed_array);

//query dataabase
foreach ($clean_array as $trimm){
     $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM forumlist WHERE `keys` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($trimm) . "%' ORDER BY rating DESC, total_ratings DESC") or die(mysql_error());
```

Thank you!

Comment: u need to run array_unique on the results from db

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//query dataabase
$query = 'SELECT * FROM forumlist  ';
$where = array();
foreach ($clean_array as $trimm){
     $where[] = " `keys` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($trimm) . "%' ";
}

if(!empty($where)){
    $query .= " WHERE ". implode(' OR ', $where);
}
$query .= " ORDER BY rating DESC, total_ratings DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: That works. It gets rid of the duplicate results. However I now get this error:

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE `keys` LIKE '%computer%' OR `keys` LIKE '%programming%' ORDER BY ratin' at line 1.

Thanks for your help

Comment: please show me the whole query. by using echo $query, before mysql_query()

Comment: It is something with the second search term. I tried the query as "computer programming" and this is the echo statement: SELECT * FROM forumlist WHERE `keys` LIKE '%computer%' ORDER BY rating DESC, total_ratings DESC. The correct links that should return from "computer" do return, however the links from "programming" do not.

Comment: is it complete query after using "computer programming"

Comment: It seems that it runs through the query and display process for "computer" and then shows the error I printed above. For example, "computer" has 2 unique results. "programming" has 2 unique results. "computer programming" returns the 2 results for "computer" and then an error message. "lollipop computer" returns 0 results and the error message.

Comment: `code`// trim whitespace

$trimmed = trim($q);
// seperate key-phrases
$trimmed_array = explode(" ", $trimmed);

// remove duplicates

$clean_array = array_unique($trimmed_array);

// check for empty string and display message

if ($trimmed == "") {
 echo "<b><p>Search Error</p><p>Please enter a search...</p></b>";
}

else {
     
//query dataabase
$query = 'SELECT * FROM forumlist  ';
$where = array();
foreach ($clean_array as $trimm){
     $where[] = " `keys` LIKE '%" . mysql_real_escape_string($trimm) . "%' ";
`code`

Comment: `code` if(!empty($where)){
    $query .= " WHERE ". implode(' OR ', $where);
}
$query .= " ORDER BY rating DESC, total_ratings DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  
// number of results

$row_num_links = mysql_num_rows($result);

// check for results

if ($row_num_links == 0) { 
 echo "<b><p>No Results Found</p><p>Please Try Again</p></b>";
}
else {

`code`

And then the displaying of the results, which I am sure works fine since the entire code works with just a single search term. "computer" for instance.

Comment: OMG. It just a silly mistake, I made. I forget to add `}` for `for loop`.

Comment: You know what, I had } at the end for my original code, so I left it there for yours. My fault.

Thanks a ton for your help